# Convergence of $f(x)e^{-tx}$ implies the convergence of $f(x)$?

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x) > 0$ on $[a,\infty)$, are integrable on $[a,b]$ whenever $0<a<b<\infty$. Suppose there is a constant $M$ s.t. $\forall t > 0$
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-tx}dx \le M \quad 
$$

Then how to prove that $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges as well?

The uniform upper bound $M$ must be the key point, but I don't know how to handle it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $f(x) = x$ a counterexample?

Comment: @Deepak No, look at the order of the quantifiers, the constant $M$ cannot depend on $t$

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks, that is a subtle point. I stand corrected.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I actually hate when people place the $\forall$ after the equation ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is true by Fatou's Lemma for instance (or the monotone convergence theorem). Indeed the sequence of functions $f_t(x) = f(x)\,e^{-tx}$ is a sequence of positive functions that converges pointwise to $f(x)$ when $t\to 0$ (you can take $t=1/n$ if you want a true sequence). Therefore, $f(x)$ is measurable and
$$
0\leq \int f(x) \,\mathrm d x \leq \liminf_t \int f_t(x) \,\mathrm d x \leq M
$$
so $f = |f|$ is integrable.